# Not getting expected answer

Tags: ruby

Code not returning the correct answer.

I've tired assigning a value to the animal choices. I've put it in the def and outside of it.

```
puts "Choose your favorite: cats or dogs"
choose = gets
cats = 1
dogs = 2

def favorite_animal (number)

    remainder_when_divided_by_2 = number % 2

    if remainder_when_divided_by_2 == 0
       return "Ken does too."
    end

    if remainder_when_divided_by_2 == 1
       return "Dogs are better!"
    end
end
```

If the user enters Cats the answer "Ken does too!" should show. If the user enters Dogs the answer "Dogs are better!" should show. All I've gotten is 1 or 2 as an answer.

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `favorite_animal`

Comment: @JoshBrody: that won't do much good if the input is `"cats\n"`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am in my third day of class so I don't know how to do what you suggest. I tired typing it like this Cats = gets.number.to_i but it gives an error message.

Comment: I had puts favorite_animal at the end so it would post the answer but that gives an error message.

Comment: So you're participating in an organized education activity of some sort ("a class"). Can you maybe ask the professor or a fellow student to walk this through with you? Stackoverflow is not well-suited for mentoring-style communication. And it looks like you need some help with the content of past three days.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
loop do
  puts "Choose your favorite: cats or dogs"
  case gets.chomp
  when "cats"
    break "Ken does too."
  when "dogs"
    break "Dogs are better!"
  else
    puts "That answer is invalid. Try again"
  end
end
```

Here is an example of a session using this code, with my answers being "pigs" and "dogs".

```
Choose your favorite: cats or dogs
pigs
That answer is invalid. Try again
Choose your favorite: cats or dogs
dogs
  #=> "Dogs are better!"
```

See [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop). Many Rubyists use `loop` with the keyword `break` for most loops, rather than `while` or `until`. (`for` loops are *never* used).

For what you are doing you don't need a method, but if you want one add the line

```
def favorite_animal
```

at the beginning and the line

```
end
```

at the end. Then

```
favorite_animal
  #=> "Dogs are better!"
```

provided I were to give the same answers as I did earlier.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things going on:

- You have to call the method `favorite_animal` somewhere; you've only defined it
- Your cats/dogs isn't "mapped" to anything, so you need some logic to convert your input into a number, before you call the `favorite_animal` method
- You still have to do something with the value you return inside your method (`puts` or something else to get it to show)

Here's a minimum example that works that might be useful for you to see the 3 issues above

```
def favorite_animal (number)
    remainder_when_divided_by_2 = number % 2

    if remainder_when_divided_by_2 == 0
      return "Ken does too."
    end

    if remainder_when_divided_by_2 == 1
      return "Dogs are better!"
    end
end

puts "Choose your favorite: cats or dogs"
choose = gets.chomp

answer = if choose == 'cats'
  1
else
  2
end

puts favorite_animal(answer)
```